# ESP32-WROOM-32E Custom PCB Failure to send LoRa Packet

Tags: arduino, pcb, spi, esp32, lora

I am having troubles trying to send a LoRa packet to a receiver. In the serial monitor I am stuck in the while loop and it keeps printing dots. Below is my code and I will attach a photo of the eagle design.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

//define the pins used by the transceiver module
#define ss 15
#define rst 18
#define dio0 34

void setup() {
  // initialize Serial Monitor 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
  Serial.println("LoRa Sender");

  // setup LoRa transceiver module
  LoRa.setPins(ss, rst, dio0);

  // replace the LoRa.begin(---E-) argument with your location's frequency
  // 433E6 for Asia
  // 866E6 for Europe
  // 915E6 for North America

  while (!LoRa.begin(915E6)) {
    Serial.println(".");
    delay(500);
  }

  // Change sync word (0xF3) to match the receiver
  // The sync word assures you don't get LoRa messages from other LoRa transceivers
  // ranges from 0-0xFF
  LoRa.setSyncWord(0xF3);
  Serial.println("LoRa Initializing OK!");
}

void loop() {
  static int counter = 0;
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(counter);

  // Send LoRa packet to receiver
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("hello ");
  LoRa.print(counter);
  LoRa.endPacket();

  counter++;
  delay(10000);  
}
```

I am unsure why LoRa won't initialize and would really like some help! I've tried everything I can think of to fix it.

Comment: The link in the question starts with ``https://file///Users/marenrogers`` and so isn't accessible. Can you edit the question to insert pictures from the document.

Comment: I don't know if PDF is a valid image format but try to upload the pdf as an image, or convert it to .jpg .png etc and upload.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a valid web link to the PDF, i.e. the link that you downloaded it from.

Comment: @Greenonline It is probably not on the web, the now deleted link was pointing to a local file path, as it's the users own work.

Comment: @MiNiMe Is this a PDF that the OP made themselves? If so, it might be better to just upload the images (unless there was text as well, in the PDF).

Comment: That's how I interpret *I will attach a photo of the eagle design.* + See my first comment